# watchOS2 and NSLog on device

Tags: watchkit, xcode7, watchos-2

I am using XCode 7 (beta) to write standalone *watchOS2* App Extension.

Debugger works fine, so I can use breakpoints for example, but seems to be that `NSLog()` is not working for the Watch. **Note**: *It works fine on simulator, but doesn't work on device*

Whatever I write to `NSLog(@"..")` is not displayed in ***Debug Area***.

*So the question is:*

Is this behavior expected or am I doing something wrong? Are there some workarounds to see some debug logs, may be use WatchConnectivity for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which target are you starting? If you are starting the iOS target then it will log for the iPhone but if you start the Watch target then it should NSLog.

Comment: I use watch target, otherwise it will not debug watch extension

Comment: Ok I use NSLogs when I´m debugging on the simulator. It works. Will investigate a little bit in my project and get back to you if I experience this.

Comment: It works fine on simulator.. I should've mentioned that, sorry. It doesn't work on real device. I edited my question not to confuse people

Comment: Did you attach the running process to Xcode? Go to Debug -> Attach to process in Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried to check the logs on the watch itself? Window -> Devices, select your paired iPhone, then click on arrow down at the bottom and select paired watch. This will show you the logs from the watch

Answer (score 0):

Until NSLog() works on real watchOS 2 devices I've ended up using -[WCSession sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:] to send log strings from my watchOS 2 app back to my iOS phone app and then NSLog them from my phone app.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this one](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3671)?

It's a known issue on developer forum.

You have to unpair and re-pair your watch to trust your computer.

Then you could see NSLog in Debug area.